# Delete users from csv file JAVA

Tags: java, csv

I have a file called "test.csv" that contains information from path1 (users) and I am reading a new file "discardUsers". What I want to do is compare the information in "test.csv" with the file "discardUsers" and delete the users that exist in discardUsers of test.csv. How could I do it? Thank you in advice.

This is what I have:

```
public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            FileWriter newFile = null;
            PrintWriter pw = null;
            String csvDelimiter = ";";
            String[] arrayD = null;
            String[] arrayU = null;


            File discardUsersFile = new File("path1");
            File usersFile = new File("path2");

            newFile = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\test.csv");
            pw = new PrintWriter(newFile);

            List<String> discardUsers = Files.readAllLines(discardUsersFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            List<String> users = Files.readAllLines(usersFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            for (String line : users) {
                arrayU = line.split(csvDelimiter);
                pw.print(arrayU[0] + csvDelimiter + arrayU[1] + csvDelimiter + arrayU[2]);                          
            }           
            if (null != newFile)
                newFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

-----[image]

Comment: Could you show us how those files look? Are those files huge? If yes, consider `Files.lines()`.

Comment: They are not large files, but I would like to compare column 0 of one with column 2 of another and perform the deletion of those users.

Comment: Well, I'd read the "delete users" file first and build a set of users to delete. Then read the actual file line by line, check whether the user is in that set and if not you write the line to a target file. For handling CSV I'd suggest using a proper CSV library such as [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) - that will make handling different delimiters, escaping etc. much easier.

Comment: The problem here is the lack of information about the csv files. Do they have *equal lines* to be removed from the test.csv or does the possible removal only rely on a single column (e.g. ID, name) of the DiscardedUsers.csv because the remaining columns might be different?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Map<String, String>` to track your user information in the form Key: user ID, Value: file string, and a `Set<String>` of discarded user IDs and then use [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll) function to remove all discarded users.

With your current code using lists instead, you will need to scan the full list everytime to check if the user you are considering exists in the discarded list and only add it to result file if not, something like:

```
for (String line : users) {
    arrayU = line.split(csvDelimiter);
    Boolean found = false;

    for(String line : discardedUsers){
        arrayD = line.split(csvDelimiter);
        if(arrayU[INDEX_OF_USER_ID].equalsIgnoreCase(arrayD[INDEX_OF_USER_ID]){
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if(!found){
        pw.print(arrayU[0] + csvDelimiter + arrayU[1] + csvDelimiter + arrayU[2]);
    }                     
}
```

I would really suggest to go with the `Map` and `Set` approach instead, something like:

```
//user ID, file line
Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
for(String line: Files.readAllLines(usersFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
    users.add(line.split(csvDelimiter)[INDEX_OF_USER_ID], line);
}

//user ID
final Set<String> discardedUsers = new HashSet<>();
for(String line: Files.readAllLines(discardUsersFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
    discardedUsers.add(line.split(csvDelimiter)[INDEX_OF_USER_ID]);
}

if(users.keySet().removeAll(discardedUsers)){
    for(String user : users){
        pw.print(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing the objects in List, you can removeAll methods to delete the users from test list.

For example
users.removeAll(discardUsers); will remove all the discard users from the userlist.

Comment: I would extend this answer to include that it will only work if the lines in the two files are identical

Comment: @Lewis, It would be good if you share your csv file structure.